# Refused to connect website hosted in Windows 7 Pro

Tags: networking, iis, windows-7

I know it is not ideal to have a website hosted in Windows 7 Pro but unfortunately I need to do some testing in a VMWare environment so after installing IIS 7 and creating a simple website I noticed I cannot access it outside the network.

I can see the website with /localhost/ and with the local IP address just fine. (I disabled Windows Firewall completely.) I can access the website from another computer inside the network. But when I try to see it from the external IP it refuses the connection immediately.

Am I missing something in the IIS configuration?

Comment: Do you have any antivirus software running in that Windows?

Comment: No antivirus installed. I also turned off Windows Defender with no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, it was an issue with the site bindings. I had my network configured to port forward 8080 but in the binding it only had port 80. So I changed it to port 8080 and it worked.